# If # is present, calculate the total, if all #s are not calculated, let the total still be calculated

Tags: javascript, jquery

as you can see in the picture, it would be silly for the user to have to type in all 5 Requested Brands (as that is not required). Maybe they only want to choose one Requested Brand. As it is currently set up, the subtotal is only calculated if the user enters 5 unit costs and 5 quantities...not good. If they don't enter all 5, subtotal returns NaN.

[image: req brands]

```
$("a#full_sub_total").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var first = $("div#total_result").text();
  var second = $("div#total_result1").text();
  var third = $("div#total_result2").text();
  var fourth = $("div#total_result3").text();
  var fifth = $("div#total_result4").text();

  $("#full_total_results p").text((parseInt(first,10) + parseInt(second,10) + parseInt(third,10) + parseInt(fourth,10) + parseInt(fifth,10)));

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Heh, how exactly do I do that? Ask less noob questions? ;)

Comment: Oh I see, I did not know that (honestly). I'll do that.

Comment: I'm sure the people who helped you will very much appreciate it! :)

Comment: The problem your full total results in NaN is that anytime one or more of individual line total is empty, it will cause your overall result total to equal NaN.

Comment: Yep VajNyiaj, I realize that, that's why I posted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop over the `total_result` fields, and incrementally add their parsed values to a total var:

```
$("a#full_sub_total").on("click", function(){
  var total = 0;
  $("div[id^=total_result]").text(function(i,t){
    total += parseInt( t, 10 ) || 0;
  });
  $(".full_total").text("$" + total);
});
```

Note the main part of all of this:

```
total += parseInt( t, 10 ) || 0;
```

When the attempt to parse an integer from the text of the element fails, we return 0 in its place. This will not offset the total value, and will permit us to continue along with out any `NaN` showing up later.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/axowew/2/edit

Comment: Hey Jonathan, this makes alot of sense to me. So where it says $("div[id^=total_result]").text(function(i,t){
    total += parseInt( t, 10 ) || 0; I'm going to have to do this five times correct? Once for total_result, then again for total_result1, then for total_result2, and so on. Or am I overthinking it?

Comment: Or is that id^= taking care of that? Sorry, very new to this.

Comment: Sickkkk, got it! That id^= thing is the shit! I was getting a method error with 'on', so I just changed it to .click(function(event){...

Comment: @DavidPardy You shouldn't be getting any method errors for `$.on` unless you're using an older version of jQuery. `$.on` was introduced in version 1.7, I believe. It is the preferred method now for binding events.

Comment: Hm, I'm new (and noob) to this project and we are using spree 0.54 and rails 3.0.7.

Comment: @DavidPardy You can tell what version of jQuery you're using with `alert( $.fn.jquery )`.

Answer (score 1):

Basic technique:

```
var sum = 0;

var num1 = parseInt(text1, 10);
if (!isNaN(num1)) sum += num1;
// ...
```

(Loops: even better idea.)

Comment: Sweet, was just trying something along those lines, will let you know!

Comment: Silly question @Amadan, how exactly does if (!isNaN(num1)) read? "If the variable num1 is not equal to a number, then the sum variable adds the value of num1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your overall total results in NaN is that anytime one or more of individual line total is empty, it will cause your overall result total to equal NaN in your attempt to add (i.e.  #+#=#, #+NaN=Nan)

Simplify solution to your problem:

```
$('#subtotal').click(function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();

// Clear overall total
$('#overallTotal').empty();

// Loop through each line total
$('div.lineTotal').each(function() {
// If line total is not empty, add
if ($(this).text() != ''){
$('#overallTotal').text(parseInt($('#overallTotal').text) += parseInt($(this).text()));
}
});
```

});